# Doxygen - \copydoc warning: target of \copydoc command not found

Tags: c++, doxygen

Here is a C++ file `testClassX.cpp`:

```
namespace abc {
namespace def {

class testClassX::innerClassX {
/*! \brief blah blah
 * \details prints stuff out
 */

/*! 
 * \brief just prints stuff 
 */
void printIt() {
    printStuff();
}


/*! 
 * \brief just says yes 
 */
bool getYes() {
    return true;
}
}

testClassX::testClassX() {
    innerClassX_ = new innerClassX;
}

/*! \copydoc testClassX::InnerClassX::printIt() */
void testClassX::printIt() {
    innerClassX_->printIt();
}

/*! \copydoc testClassX::InnerClassX::getYes() */
bool testClassX::getYes() {
    return innerClassX_->getYes();
}

} // namespace def
} // namespace abc
```

When run through doxygen, the above file yields:

```
Warning: target testClassX::innerClassX::getYes() of \copydoc command not found
```

However, there is no warning message for `printIt()`. Is this because it does not return any parameters?

What is wrong in the above example? How can I get rid of those `\copydoc` related warnings?

EDIT: I discovered the solution to this problem. I set following properties in the `Doxyfile` to YES and Doxygen found the inner classes:

```
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES (I think this one was not necessary, but I needed it for another unrelated reason.)
```

Comment: On first sight I'd agree with Doxygen - I can't see the doxygen for load() either, whereas the doxygen for PrintIt does exist, so it can be copied.  Could you explain what you are expecting to happen (or perhaps edit the question to be clearer)?

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes in the code posted above, I have fixed them now.

Comment: Does the problem still appear when you use the fully qualified name instead? (like `\copydoc abc::def::testClassX::InnerClassX::printIt()`)

Comment: Are you sure that code is right even now?  What's "Catalog"?

Comment: cheeseminer, you are correct, I fixed the code now.

Comment: Hi ComicSansMS, I tried to use the fully qualified name too, but had the same result.

Comment: I discovered the solution to this problem.
I set following properties in the doxyfile to YES and, hey presto, copydoc statements found the inner classes:

EXTRACT_ALL           = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE       = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC        = YES

I think EXTRACT_STATIC was not necessary to fix this, but I needed it for another (unrelated) reason.